# Issue with CodeIgniter hiding non-CI global variables when including outside code

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope, global-variables, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to introduce CI into a legacy application but want to use some of the globals that already exist externally from CI. I have been loading them into /CI/config/config.php and acquiring them using this in the view:

$this->config->item('myvar');

That works fine. However, if I include my sidebar in the model called sidebar.php, which wants to access the globals stored in globals.php they come up as undefined. Note that sidebar.php uses a include statement to access globals from globals.php. Also, the globals are defined like this in globals.php:
$myvar = "bla";

globals.php and sidebar.php are outside of CI. These two files don't need to execute functions.

Does anyone know of a trick to allow CI and files it includes to access globals outside of it? I don't want to change the legacy code too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I found an include_once statement for the globals.php file in a place where the legacy code couldn't access it. The legacy code already had an include_once statement but it was ignored b/c it was already included elsewhere.

I assume that it's acting similar to this in CI if I open testfile.php:

**testfile.php:**

```
include_once("globals.php");

function testf(){
  include("sidebar.php");
}

testf();
```

**sidebar.php**

```
include_once("globals.php");

echo $myvar; //fails
```

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter provides a useful helper function to solve these kinds of situations. The get_instance() function will return the singleton object so that you can access it's many wonderful features.  Below is an example of how you might do this.

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->config->item('varname');
```

Here is the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).  You'll find the reference under the title **Utilizing CodeIgniter Resources within Your Library**

Comment: Thanks. At some point I think we will probably like to move our globals to CI, but still need to depend on external ones.